# Two threads are waiting for each other, not able to resolve

Tags: java, multithreading

There are two methods one pushes the message to arraylist and other retrieves the messages from the arraylist. Both methods are synchronized. 
I have created two threads,one to push the message into arraylist and other to retrieve. Two threads are in a deadlock situation.How to resolve it

Below is the code to push and display messages

```
public class FetchCurrentTime {

    static final int MAXMESSAGE = 5;
    private List<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();

    public synchronized void putTime(){
        while(messages.size() != MAXMESSAGE){
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            messages.add(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()).toString());
        }
        notify();

    }

    public synchronized String getTime(){
        String message= "Unable to fetch time";
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(!message.isEmpty()){
        message = messages.remove(messages.size()-1);
        }
        notify();
        return message;
    }

}
```

Below is the Producer and consumer code

```
public class ProduceTime extends Thread {
    FetchCurrentTime fc ;

    public ProduceTime(FetchCurrentTime fc) {
            this.fc = fc;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        fc.putTime();
    }

}


public class ConsumeTime extends Thread {
    FetchCurrentTime fc ;
    public ConsumeTime(FetchCurrentTime fc) {
        this.fc = fc;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            String time = fc.getTime();
            System.out.println(time);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the code to test.

```
public class GetDate {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        FetchCurrentTime fc = new FetchCurrentTime();
        ProduceTime p = new ProduceTime(fc);
        ConsumeTime c = new ConsumeTime(fc);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(p);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(c);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: Describe in words what your `putTime` is doing.

Comment: Are you testing out the wait and notify methods?  Modern Java code does not use notify and wait.  There exists higher order classes and methods for working in a multithreaded application.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis putTime gets the current time and adds the time to arraylist of string. I made putTime and getTime methods synchronzied so that while putTime is inserting messages into arraylist, getTime should not retrieve the message from arraylist and display it

Comment: Describe the _code_, specifically.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis This is an example of  producer and consumer problem. FetchCurrentTime class has two methods.Method putTime fetches the current time and adds this as String to ArrayList messages.  GetTime retrieves the last element in the arraylist message and prints it in the console.

Comment: You're not understanding my comment. What is the first thing your `putTime` method calls within its `while` loop? Also, you're creating two instances of `FetchCurrentTime`.

Comment: Your producer and consumer don't share the array list. There's nothing to synchronize. Also, the error is quite obvious. What Sotirios means is: When you describe your functions to yourself, you will find the error. Another hint: Who is calling `notify()`?

Comment: @1000ml I have edited the question now, now the producer and consumer share the same arraylist. How to make it synchronized? Is wait and notify required both in putTime and getTime

Comment: From how I see this, since you have two instances of `FetchCurrentTime`, your ArrayList isn't shared; it still is bound to its own instance. Also, in the `putTime` and `getTime` methods, you are invoking `wait()` first. Since `messages` start with 0, both the methods would wait for the other to call notify, which I don't think would ever occur.

Comment: @Prathap See the code to test, there is only one of instance of FetchCurrentTime

Comment: This segment of code makes it clearer. I see that the issue with the `wait()` and `notify()` calls. I have provided a code snippet as an answer. Try it out.

Comment: @Prathap It helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that the issue is with when `wait()` is being called in `getTime()` and `putTime()`, as both wait for the other to notify; which never occurs.
Also, there is a typo in `getTime()`, should be `messages.isEmpty()` (list) and not `message.isEmpty()` (String)

You could give this code a try. Note that it runs forever, so you will need to handle the termination conditions.

```
public synchronized void putTime() {

    while (true) {  // To ensure list contains 5 elements at any point of time before removal
        if (messages.size() >= MAXMESSAGE) {
            try {
                wait(); // wait issued only when list is full
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        while (messages.size() < MAXMESSAGE) {
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            messages.add(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()).toString());
        }

        notify();   // notify getTime() to resume execution
    }
}

public synchronized String getTime() {
    String message = "Unable to fetch time";

    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);  // adding delay to help see the output

        if (messages.isEmpty()) {
            wait(); // wait for putTime() to add messages to the list
        }

        if (!messages.isEmpty()) {
            message = messages.remove(messages.size() - 1);
            notify();   // notifies putTime() to add a message to the list; helps keep count to 5
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return message;
}
```

That said, it is recommended to use the advanced Thread constructs which help achieve the same (much easier) with a better throughput.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

please find the below issues in your code.

1. Provide initial time for producer to generate number, hence include Thread.sleep(100) in consumer thread.
2. Threads have to wait() at below criteria.
   a). Consumer Thread - wait() only if array.size() is zero. 
   b). Producer Thread - wait() only if array.size() >= MAX_SIZE.

Note - use notifyAll instead of notify.

Answer (score -1):

There are lots of ways to solve this problem.  A deadlock can occur any time where there are two or more locks acquired by two threads in different *orders*.  The ordering is a critical part.

E.g. if one thread can acquire the put lock, and the other acquires the get lock, then vice versa, there's a dead lock.  If each thread always acquires the get lock first, then the put lock, and releases the put lock before releasing the get lock, then a deadlock is impossible.

To resolve, make the locks explicit (e.g.: synchronized(lockObject){ /* the code */ }), and either always acquire the locks in order, or only use one lock.

Another solution would be to use an actor framework like Akka.  An actor abstracts away the locking, and is particularly suitable to sending and receiving messages.  With an actor, there's a "mailbox" with synchronized access to add messages from other threads, but the actor itself processes messages serially in its one thread.

Comment: If you're going to down-vote, might want to let me know why.

Comment: You're talking about deadlocks in general but don't explain how it applies to their question at all. Then you bring in Akka for some reason. You're completely missing the point. The comments on the question do a better job describing the issues. You may want to include them in your answer.

Comment: The specific question was "Two threads are in a deadlock situation.How to resolve it."  Either acquiring locks in order, or using akka, will remove deadlocks.  I answered the question as it was written, I'm not going to write his code for him.

Comment: Read between the lines. _These two threads are in a deadlock situation. How do I resolve *this* situation._ To make your answer useful, describe what that situation is, why there is a deadlock in this situation, and how they could resolve it. You don't need to write any code. Otherwise, just flag (or vote once you have enough reputation) to close as one of the thousands of duplicates about deadlocks that are out there.